# SFTP::Foreign (Perl Library) login issue using RAS key

Tags: perl, sftp, hp-ux

I am facing a very strange problem with SFTP::Foreign while trying to log in a remote machine from HP-UX. Strange is that the issue is very hard to reproduce. The program which uses SFTP::Foreign to log in, runs every work day at the same time and once in a week or two it fails. It uses RSA key for authentication to server.

I enabled -vvv for tracing and I was hoping that here I'll find some help. I captured logs when authentication is successful and when it failed. Below I will put parts of the logs when the difference started

This is a part of the log when logging in is successful

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <intentionally hidden by me>
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: <intentionally hidden by me>
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: <intentionally hidden by me>
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

This is part when logging fails

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: <intentionally hidden by me>
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In the second case, the client is offering a key to the server and the server isn't accepting it. The server does not tell the client why it didn't accept the key. You would have to troubleshoot that on the server. The server should have its own logs which might be helpful.

Comment: @Kenster Here it gets more strange- server doesn't get any logs of unsuccessful login attempts

Comment: @Kenster I happens extremely rare with other servers. I suspected that firewall drops, but this doesn't really make sense- firewall rules are definitive so the packet would be dropped all the time.

Comment: The client is connecting to some server and getting through the ssh protocol to the point of trying to authenticate. If the server isn't logging anything about the connection attempt, I'd suspect the client might be connecting to the wrong server somehow.

Comment: @Kenster That is scary, but not the case. On top of the logs I see that the communication was established with the correct IP. The direction of my though is that the log that "debug2: we sent a public key packet, wait for reply" does not reflect what happens in reality, because I should've get a reply from server. My next steps is to capture network traffic and actually check packets (in case I don't get an answer here), but it might take some time till I am able to reproduce the issue